# Can't center both textview and imageview

Tags: android

I'm trying to center elements from a gridview, but I'm having some issues doing that.

My column layout looks like this:

[image]

And I want it to look like this:

[image]

Column layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="110dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_name"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

My gridview:

```
    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gvApps"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    tools:listitem="@layout/app_row"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />
```

What do I need to change on my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below with `LinearLayout` and orientation `vertical`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="110dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_name"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to use `RelativeLayout`, then it should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="110dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:id="@+id/app_name"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also you can achieve it using `ConstraintLayout` like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:id="@+id/app_name"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_logo"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:text="TextView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```